# How to specify max-height css property to Screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am  trying with the following style:

```
.scrollDiv {
    height:auto;
    max-height:100%;
    overflow:auto;   
}
```

My Requirement is:

1. `max-height` of div is equal to screen height
2. If the content in the div exceeds screen size, then scroll bars should come in div.

Comment: Actually i'm using this div in a popup window.

Comment: Why not use the scroll bar that would normally appear on the window?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Scroll bar appears only when content is `overflown`.

If `max-height` of your inner div is equal to the height of its container, scroll bar will never appear. if you want to see scroll bar use this.

```
.scrollDiv {
    height:auto;
    max-height:150%;
    overflow:auto;   
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this answer is relevant, but I wanted to point out that it is easy to make the scroll bar visible even if nothing over flows. overflow:scroll;

Comment: no i meant if he wants to tee scroll bar 'when' content is overflown, in his case content will never overflow and what's the point of a scroll bar if content is not overflown?

Comment: How would you not allow anything in the div to exceed the height and width? In other words, the max height and max widtth is based on the screen size.

Answer (score 144):

Use CSS Viewport units for this.

Example:

```css
.scrollDiv {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. I did have to set max-height to 77vh for my case.

Comment: @JohnRix not the downvoter, but 1) CSSFools, and 2) .asp are both good reasons to downvote IMVHO

Comment: This answer is amazing, thank you! And @user234461 is probably right, people really don't like w3schools.

Comment: I guess it seems to have fallen out of favour a little over the years (though perhaps not so much so as the likes of SourceForge!). I still find it answers most of my questions when Google gives it back to me as a search result though.

Comment: Right there with you John.  If often answers the question quickly and simply.  More often than not... that is good enough.  Either way this is the best answer to the question presented.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen vh or vw...  What rock have I been hiding under?  Awesome!

Comment: Absolutely excellent.. didn't know about vh, thanks!

Answer (score 29):

You can use `$(window).height()` to set the max-height to screen height:

```
$('.scrollDiv').css('max-height', $(window).height());
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the John's answer. With the latest [CSS3 API](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) you can use `vh`'s([View port unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) for height)

```
.scrollDiv {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Using JavaScript is a massive pain compared to pure CSS as the code would have to be called every time the window was resized.